# Why does scp has an exit status of 0 after reporting an error?

Tags: linux, scp

Whether on Linux or Cygwin, I get the following (note the invalid space in the username):

```
>scp file.txt "invalid user@host.com:file.txt"
invalid user: invalid user name
>echo $?
0
```

Why is the exit status 0?

Note: I'm aware of the [known bug](https://www.fir3net.com/UNIX/General/why-does-scp-file-transfer-fail-but-there-is-no-error.html) related to scp failing silently - but in the above case an error is printed to stderr.

Comment: Feel free to report it to OpenSSH as a bug.

Comment: @Kenster Done :)
https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a bug. I [reported](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2771) it.